# Import csv file and use "toggle editing" and "field calculator" without Saving it as a Shapefile.

Tags: qgis, shapefile, field-calculator, import, csv

I am importing a .csv file in QGIS and I have also made the *.csvt file where I have specified my data types. I still cannot use "Toggle editing" and "field calculator".Whether I must save it as a shapefile and import it again?
Is there any way to work with the .csv file without saving  it as a shapefile and import it again?

Comment: How did u imported the .Csv file? via any plugin?

Comment: As far as I know, no. It brings it in as a non editable 'virtual layer' - you must save it to an OGR editable file first.